# Is Response.Write() working with Razor?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-3

Is Response.Write() working with Razor?

I tried to use `@Html.RenderAction` but I'm getting the error:

```
CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 
'Microsoft.WebPages.WebPageUltimateBase.Write(Microsoft.WebPages.Helpers.HelperResult)'   
has some invalid arguments
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Index", "Menu");}
```

Or just using Action:

```
@Html.Action("Index", "Menu")
```

Comment: stacker's got it.  It's like using <%= to call a method that returns Void, you get a compiler error about not finding a correct overload.  "@Foo" <==> "<%= Foo %>" and "@{Foo}" <==> "<% Foo %>"

Comment: In the MVC 3 RTM I get this 'No overload for method 'Write' takes 0 arguments' - so I'm not convinced it works anymore. Would love to be corrected though since Html.Action doesn't take a lambda and I'm forced to use RenderAction instead. [oh and I get this error whether I use a lambda or not]

Comment: +1 I would only add that it is advertised as preferable to use RenderAction as it outputs to the response stream without string creation.