# How can I specify a namespace when calling @Html.Action(...) in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionmethod

When I try to use `Html.Action` in ASP.NET MVC 3 for a controller in a different namespace from the current controller I get an error :

**Code:**

```
@Html.Action("Foo", "Application", new { id = "FG2" })
```

**Error :**

> The controller for path
>   '/rrmvc/store/checkout' was not
>   found or does not implement
>   IController.

This error only occurs when the controller `ApplicationController` is in a different NAMESPACE from the current controller such as `StoreControllers.CheckoutController` (in fact they're in completely different areas too).

Is there no way to specify a namespace when calling `Html.Action` (none of the obvious ways like fully qualifying the namespace seem to work)?

There are no lambda methods to use, and I had [no luck using `Html.RenderAction`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383618/is-response-write-working-with-razor/3383674#3383674) in MVC3 RTM.

---

*Edit* : I think it might be related to the area - or perhaps this could be a complete red herring too. I have another controller in a different namespace that DOES work correctly - so I think the problem is more complicated. I'll reply with an answer if i figure it out - or just delete this question if not to avoid confusion!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the controller is in a different area you may try specifying this area name:

```
@Html.Action("Foo", "Application", new { id = "FG2", area = "foo" })
```

and if you are already inside the area and you want to render an action located on a controller in the root you could try this:

```
@Html.Action("Foo", "Application", new { id = "FG2", area = "" })
```

Comment: Thank you SO much. This is one of those 3 hour problems that I could have easily worked around in numerous ways - but I just couldn't let it go. This worked just great. Thanks. All this to print out the numeric size of my generated CSS in the footer of the page!

Comment: If anyone else comes across this problem it was the second example here that worked for me - the 'Application' controller was not present in any area - and setting area="" allowed it to be found